# How to use API instead of using Google BigQuery Data Transfer Service?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-bigquery, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create BigQuery Data transfer config for Google Adwords through API using a programming language (Python, Java). I looked at the documentation about BigQuery data transfer API. But there is no proper process for that. Maybe I could not understand properly. Can anyone help me in understanding how to use API to get daily analytic data from YouTube instead of paying YouTube to use their BigQuery Data transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get started using Adwords SQL

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call

Refer to the [Getting Started section of the Python client library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) README file to download and install the AdWords API client library for Python.